# Is this an example of "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, too-localized

I'm reading [Error while doing RSA Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427383/error-while-doing-rsa-decryption), which has just been answered by the author. Apparently a small coding error was the cause of the problem.

Is this a candidate for closure as "too localized"? Any tips for deciding whether a coding error has merit for future readers?

Comment: I'd say that's a good call. The question is a gigantic code dump with what appears to be a trivial solution.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The deciding factor should be "unlikely to help any future visitors". That often applies to oops-I-was-wrong questions but not so much in this case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The question is definitely unlikely to help future visitors. The title describes some unspecified error occurred while working with RSA Decryption. What was the error? The OP forgot to decode the the `encrypted` string before passing it to `doFinal`. Highly unlikely to help anyone, since this sort of problem should be identified on your first readthrough after you hit an exception. You shouldn't post to SO first, *then* do the debugging that is required and post that as an answer.

Comment: @Asad Would you care to post that as an answer? I think that's the correct viewpoint and I'd like to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is definitely unlikely to help future visitors. The title only conveys that some unspecified error occurred while working with RSA Decryption, and the problem is almost entirely obscured by red herring code blocks. What was the error? The OP forgot to decode the the encrypted string before passing it to `doFinal`. That was it.

I sincerely doubt this will help anyone in the future, since 90% of the time this sort of problem is already identified (or at least should be) on your first readthrough after you hit an exception. You shouldn't post to SO first, *then* do the your due diligence in terms of debugging and post that as an answer.

Comment: Exactly, since the OP didn't say anything about the error, there isn't anything that future readers can learn from that question. They cannot even understand if the shown solution applies to them too, since they cannot understand if the described problem is the one they are having too.

Comment: Since this is just a simple diff, it is possible to salvage the post a bit by editing.